# phonegap app icon with notifications (number)

Tags: cordova, notifications

Does phonegap application can have an app icon with a number above it which states how many unread notifications are waiting?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The two plugins refrenced in the other answers are now available on server-side PhoneGap Build too:

- `<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.badge" />`
  [(plugin 384)](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/384)
- `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />`
  [(plugin 324)](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/324)

They report to be working with latest 3.0.0 and 3.1.0 versions of PhoneGap.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning on using push notifications, you might want to use this plugin: https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

It has this function for setting the badge number:

```
pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, event.badge);
```

Comment: @Mik378 Do you know something that works for android?

Answer (score -1):

The plugin I found [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/Badge) is a bit old but it might still work.